# How to populate data in 3 level nested Formarray in Angular

Tags: angular, populate, formarray

i am using three level nested form array of angular, in which my first form array is of person, inside person form array i am having fir detail form array (employees), and inside this i have act detail (employee skill) form array.

i am able to populate person and fir detail form array but i am having trouble in populating act detail form array.

This is the code in ts file.

```
if (res && res.length > 0) {
      var indexPerson = 0
      res.map((item : any,index : any)=>{


        this.persons().push(this.newuser(item));
        indexPerson = indexPerson +1
        if(item.fir_detail){
          var indexFir = 0
          item.fir_detail.map((items: any) => {
            this.employees(index).push(this.newValue(items));
            
            // if(items.act_detail){
            //   items.act_detail.map((actitem: any) => {
            //     var controlact:any = ""
            //     if(this.employees(0) && this.employees(0).at(indexFir)){
            //       console.log("0000000000000000")
            //       controlact = this.employees(0).at(indexFir).get('act_detail') as FormArray;
            //       controlact.push(this.existingSkill(actitem));
            //     }
                
               
                
            //     indexFir = indexFir + 1
            //   });
            // }
          });
        }

      

      })
      // this.employees().push(this.newEmployee());
    } 


newValue(item:any): FormGroup {
console.log(item)
return this.fb.group({
  fir_no: [item.fir_no],
  date: [item.date],
  police_station_id: [item.police_station_id],
  act_detail: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

}

```
existingSkill(actitem:any): FormGroup {
console.log(actitem)
return this.fb.group({
  act_id: actitem.act_id,
  section_of_law: actitem.section_of_law,
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How to populate data in 3 level nested Formarray in Angular? being careful

I imagine your arrays are arrays of FormGroups, so create three functions that return a formGroup -create from depper level- (I imagine some properties of your elements, replace by yours)

```
newSkill(data:any=null){
   data=data || {id:0,description:''}
   return this.fb.group({
      id:data.id,
      description:data.description
   })
}

newEmploy(data:any=null)
{
  data=data || {fir_no:0,date:null,police_station_id:0,act_detail:null}
  return this.fb({
    fir_no: [data.fir_no],
    date: [data.date],
    police_station_id: [data.police_station_id],
    act_detail: data.act_detail?this.fb.array([
                     data.act_detail.map(x=>this.newSkill(x)
                ]):this.fb.array([]),
  })
}
newPerson(data:any=null)
{
  data=data || {id:0,name:null,surname,employees:null}
  return this.fb({
    id: [data.id],
    name: [data.name],
    surname: [data.surname],
    employees: data.employees?this.fb.array(
                     data.employees.map(x=>this.newEmploy(x)
                ):this.fb.array([]),
  })

}
```

See how the formArray is create using `this.fb.array(data.property.map=>...)`. that's, you convert the array "data.property" in an array of FormGroups

Now you only need

```
this.persons=this.fb.array(res.map(x=>newPerson(x));
```